# Dropdown con Sub Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown

Salve a tutti,
in cosa sbaglio? la voce Punti la vedo mentre non vedo le sotto voci Gestione, Attivazione,Gruppi, Informazione.

` 



Anagrafica

```
                     <!--Punti Vendita -->
                            <ul id="puntiVendita" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle sidebar-link" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-view-dashboard"></i>
                                    <span class="hide-menu" id="titleMenu">Punti</span>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul id="itemMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><font color="#ffffff">Gestione</font></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><font color="#ffffff">Attivazione</font></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><font color="#ffffff">Gruppi</font></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><font color="#ffffff">Informazione</font></a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
```

`